# T-SQL LEFT JOIN on bigint id return only ids lower than 101 on right table

Tags: t-sql, join, left-join, bigint

I have two tables on a Sql Server 2008.
`ownership` with 3 fields and `case` with another 3 fields I need to join both on the ID field (bigint).

For testing purposes I'm only using one field from each table. This field is bigint and has values from 1 to 170 (for now).

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ownership.fCase,
    case.id
FROM
    ownership LEFT JOIN case ON (case.id=ownership.fCase)
WHERE 
    ownership.dUser='demo'
```

This was expected to return 4 rows with the same values on both columns. Problem is that the last row of the right table comes as null for the fCase = 140. This is the only value above 100.

If I run the query without the WHERE clause it show all rows on the left table but the values on the right only apear if below 101 otherwise shows null.

Can someone help me, am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation or a bug?

Comment: Is there in a row in the `case` table which has `id = 140`? (eg: what is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM case WHERE id = 140`?)

Comment: Yes the value exists, as i said from 1 to 170. in both tables.

Comment: @João Correia: have you actually checked? Or are you assuming?

Comment: I have cheked after you asked (just in case). This is actually a system that is in production (mysql) but we are poring it to SQL Server. When one case is created one ownership record is created, when a record is tranfered to another owner, a new ownership record is created, with another date and time. So to be exact there is at least one ownership record for each case.

Comment: This can't be the query you are actually running. It would give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Case is also a verb so it may be getting confused.  Try your table and column names in [].  E.G. [case].[id] = [ownership].[fCase].   Are you like double check sure that [case].[id] and  [ownership].[fCase] are both bigint. If your current values are 1-170 then why bigint (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)?  Does that column accept nulls?